# typescriptで指定した文字列のどれかを返す関数を定義したい

Tags: javascript, typescript

typescriptで書いています。あるアプリケーションでサポートする言語（locale）が限定されていて、システムがそれ以外のlocaleを返したらデフォルトのlocaleにフォールバックするための関数を書きたいです。

`/* currentLocaleがSupportedLocaleだったら */`はどう書けばいいのでしょうか？

```ts
type SupportedLocale = 'ja' | 'en';

export function currentLocale() : SupportedLocale{
  // システムからlocaleを取る。
  const currentLocale =  Localization.locale.split('-')[0];

  if(/* currentLocaleがSupportedLocaleだったら */){
    return currentLocale
  }

  return 'ja';  
}
```

型ガードあたりで検索すると、以下の様な記述というのは出てきますが、これだとサポートするlocaleが増えた時、二箇所に変更を加えるのが嫌です。

```ts
export function currentLocale() : SupportedLocale{
  const currentLocale =  Localization.locale.split('-')[0];

  if(currentLocale == 'ja' || currentLocale == 'en'){
    return currentLocale;
  }

  return 'ja';  
}
```

typeofはと思ったけど、これはそもそも`typeof currentLocale`が`string`だろうし、`'SupportedLocale' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`と言われ左辺には置けないようですね。

```ts
  if(typeof currentLocale === SupportedLocale){
    return currentLocale;
  }
```

ユーザー定義型ガードというのを見つけて使ってみたけど、結局のところ二箇所にサポートlocaleの情報が散らばってしまいます。

```ts
export type SupportedLocale = 'ja' | 'en';

const isSupportedLocale = (test: unknown): test is SupportedLocale => {
  if(test == 'ja' || test == 'en'){
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};

export function currentLocale() : SupportedLocale{
  const currentLocale =  Localization.locale.split('-')[0];

  if(isSupportedLocale(currentLocale)){
    return currentLocale;
  }

  return 'ja';  
}
```

まあ、やってることはIF文でやった型ガードを関数に切り出しただけですよね。サポートするlocaleのリストを一箇所だけに書いて、判定するにはどう書けばいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6):

許容される値の配列から Union 型を生成することで、今回の問題を簡潔に解決できます。この手法は一般的に利用できるでしょう。

```
// refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45257357
const _SupportedLocale = [
  'ja',
  'en'
] as const
type SupportedLocale = typeof _SupportedLocale[number]

// refer https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates
const _SupportedLocaleValues: readonly string[] = _SupportedLocale

function isSupportedLocale(str: string): str is SupportedLocale {
  return _SupportedLocaleValues.includes(str)
}

/* apply it to your code...
const DEFAULT_LOCALE: SupportedLocale = 'ja'

export function currentLocale(): SupportedLocale {
  const currentLocale = Localization.locale.split('-')[0]
  if (isSupportedLocale(currentLocale)) {
    return currentLocale
  }
  return DEFAULT_LOCALE
}
*/

// for example...
console.log('ja', isSupportedLocale('ja'))
// true
console.log('en', isSupportedLocale('en'))
// true
console.log('zh', isSupportedLocale('zh'))
// false
```